# MonoCecil Type.IsCOMObject equivalent?

Tags: c#, reflection, mono.cecil

I'd like to make a method that takes a TypeDefinition and tells me if it represents a COM object.
The method should also work in the .NET 4.0 "Embedded COM Interop Types"  case.

Any idea how I could do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
    public static bool IsCOMObject(TypeDefinition type)
    {
        if (type == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("type");

        return (type.Attributes & TypeAttributes.Import) == TypeAttributes.Import;
    }
```

From official reference here: [Common Language Infrastructure (CLI). Partition II: Metadata Definition and Semantics](http://download.microsoft.com/download/D/C/1/DC1B219F-3B11-4A05-9DA3-2D0F98B20917/Partition%20II%20Metadata.doc??.htm).

> 10.1 Type header (ClassHeader):
>
> Implementation-specific (Microsoft)
>
> The above grammar also includes
>   ClassAttr ::= import to indicate that
>   the type is imported from a COM type
>   library.

Comment: I tested it and this worked both for .NET 4.0 "Embedded COM Interop Types" and regular PIA COM types. Thanks!!